# Conditional expectation of monotone random variable is monotone in conditional bound

Tags: probability

Suppose a normal random variable of $X$ and Let $Y=g(X)$ where g is a continuous function that is strictly increasing. I would like to show if $\mathbb{E}[g(X)|X\geq x_e]$ is strictly increasing in bound $x_e$. Heuristic speculation says this should be true and easy to prove because you are taking expectation where $X$ is larger as lower bound $X_e$ increases.

I tried the following : 
Let $\Phi_X$ and $\phi_X$ be CDF and PDF of $X$,

$\frac{\partial\mathbb{E}[g(X)|X\geq x_e]}{\partial x_e}=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_e}\frac{\int^\infty _{x_e}g(X)f_x (x)dx}{1-\Phi_X (x_e )}
\\
=\frac{(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_e}\int^\infty _{x_e}g(X)\phi_X (x)dx)(1-\Phi_X (x_e ))+(\int^\infty _{x_e}g(X)\phi_X (x)dx)\phi_X (x_e )}{(1-\Phi_X (x_e ))^2}
\\
=\frac{-g(x_e)\phi_X (x_e)(1-\Phi_X (x_e ))+(\int^\infty _{x_e}g(X)\phi_X (x)dx)\phi_X (x_e )}{(1-\Phi_X (x_e ))^2}
\\
>0 \iff  g(x_e)\phi_X (x_e)(1-\Phi_X (x_e ))<(\int^\infty _{x_e}g(X)\phi_X (x)dx)\phi_X (x_e )
\\
\iff g(x_e)(1-\Phi_X (x_e ))<(\int^\infty _{x_e}g(X)\phi_X (x)dx)
$

Is the most mileage I can get and I do not know if the last inequality should true or not. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?

Comment: @AlainRemillard I added what I tried, though I am not sure it is the way to go,